# Scroll view doesn't visible when i am using removeFromSuperview in xcode 5 (ios 6.1 simulator)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am using xcode 5. when i was run app from xcode 5 for ios 6.1 simulator then scroll view doesn' see. for ios 7.0 simulator .Before it was working. I am using interface builder

You can see in following image.....

**In ios 7.0 simulator it is working**

**In ios 6.1 simulator** It is Totally white

![It is totally White][2]

In my scroll view view controller in viewDidLoad method i have write below code

```
 [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
 [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

**When I comment above code then  scrollview is visible For ios 6.1 simulator**

![enter image description here][3]

Seriously I dont know what is the actual reason? is that above reason or not.  In xcode 4.6 it was working .Also my app is live on appstore . Please help me .

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the Deployment Target for your Project?

Comment: Run the program and NSLog the frames, I had things really messed up when I updated to Xcode 5 (frame's being in the -1000, 2000 area).

Comment: when i comment code removefromsuperview then it is working.

Comment: @downvoter please give me  reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that You have issue with memory management or with position/size of scrollView. Try to set breakpoint and check what heppends with Your object.

Answer (score 0):

@Kalpesh its simply because removeFromSuperview doesn't work in iOS 7. So your scrollView was not removed (if you had touched the screen it would have crashed). But [scrollView removeFromSuperView]; removed the scrollView in iOS 6 .

Comment: Not actualy. I found this out while upgrading my codes for iOS 7 compatibility